# NEO4J: Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/var/lib/neo4j/import/

Tags: docker, neo4j, vagrant, cypher

I am running Neo4J on Docker within Vagrant.

I am attempting to LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from a file within the /import/ directory (I had to move my file there) via a cURL request. My request looks something like this:

```
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \"file:///insert-neo4j.csv\" AS row ...
```

This provides me with the following error:

```
{"results":[],"errors [{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed","message":"Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/var/lib/neo4j/import/insert-neo4j.csv"}]}
```

It is often suggested to me that I append the following to my '/conf/neo4j.conf' file, however this file DOES NOT EXIST, and creating it manually does not seem to work...

```
dbms.directories.import=import
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

So I created the file /conf/neo4j.conf with the above variables, and I also tried adding these as environment variables to my docker-compose file. I seem to continuously have no luck uploading via CSV this way.

My questions are:

- Is there anything blatantky wrong with this implementation?
- Why does my /conf/neo4j.conf file NOT exist and how can I get it created?

Thank you

(p.s. my insert-neo4j.csv has -rwxr-xr-x)

Comment: Do you have a NEO_HOME env var set to /var/lib/neo4j ?
I presume you installed it with apt-get. 
I advise install from archive, set NEO_HOME for your admin comfort.

Comment: Can you move your csv file into the container's directory `/var/lib/neo4j/import` ?  Otherwise do you know you can directly mount a local folder as the container neo4j import by adding this option when you launch docker : --volume=PATH_TO_MY_LOCAL_FOLDER:/import

Comment: Thank you both. I have both set NEO_HOME to my local path, moved my insert into the /import/ directory (as stated in the question), and I have just tried mounting my local /import/ directory and continue to see the "Couldn't load the external resource at ..." error.

Thanks again - will keep looking..

I would like to add that this is working fine with using an external url (like the .csv provided in neo4j docs) and I get a different error if the URL is obviously Invalid.

Comment: logisma, your answer is what ultimately allowed me to solve this problem. thank you. In my docker compose file, I declared the volumes, but could not use "/var/lib/neo4j/import", rather had to use just "/import"

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates it found the file but there is an error in the CSV ... most likely the formatting. Check this and if you can't see it, please post a few rows, including the header, of it so we might help.

Comment: thanks -- my CSV looks like this:

`"Name","Address" \n "test","test"`